# Как открыть файл в новом окне IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Мне необходимо запустить java-файл в новом окне IntelliJ IDEA через командную строку. Если запустить этот файл с любым открытым проектом, файл откроется в нем, а не в новом окне

Я попытался открыть файл, сначала открыв папку с файлом в IntelliJ IDEA, но это работает только если какой-то проект уже открыт в IntelliJ IDEA, в противном случае открывается только проект, а файл - нет.

Пытался запустить используя следующий шаблон в командной строке "path to idea" "path to project" && "path to idea" "path to java file"

Answer (score 1):

В IDEA 14 и IDEA 15 это можно найти в настройках | Внешний вид и поведение | Настройки системы → Открытие проекта. Если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: К сожалению нет. Это работает только с новыми проектами. Файлы же он открывает в последнем использованном проекте